# Get unique count of items of a column in pandas pivot table

Tags: python, pandas

Here is my code:

`df1.pivot_table(index=["Unit", "Grade"],values = ["Unit", "QTY","ORDER_NUM", "ORDER ID"], aggfunc={'Cost': 'sum' ,'QTY':'sum', "ORDER_NUM":'count',"ORDER ID":'count'})`

I want to get a count of the unique order numbers and order id. Using 'count' is not giving me a unique count. How do i do this?

Comment: Please [edit] to include a [mcve] with sample data, expected output, and code for what you've tried so far. See [pandas Series.value_counts()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) or possibly [pandas nunique()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nunique.html) depending on what you're actually asking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `'nunique'`:

example input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": ["foo", "foo", "foo", "foo", "foo",
                         "bar", "bar", "bar", "bar"],
                   "B": ["one", "one", "one", "two", "two",
                         "one", "one", "two", "two"],
                   "C": ["small", "large", "large", "small",
                         "small", "large", "small", "small",
                         "large"],
                   "D": [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
                   "E": [2, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 8, 9, 9]})
```

processing:

```
pd.pivot_table(df,
               values=['D', 'E'],
               index=['A', 'B'],
               columns=['C'],
               aggfunc={'D': 'sum',
                        'E': 'nunique',   ### HERE
                        }
               )
```

output:

```
            D           E      
C       large small large small
A   B                          
bar one   4.0   5.0   1.0   1.0
    two   7.0   6.0   1.0   1.0
foo one   4.0   1.0   2.0   1.0
    two   NaN   6.0   NaN   2.0
```